# Problem with understanding Ether log

Tags: transactions, remix

Is transaction log also called trnsaction receipt?
My account address on Remix IDE is 0xCA3…a733c and wallet address is 0x147…C160C. Following is my code obtained from [Solidity Tutorial](https://www.dappuniversity.com/articles/solidity-tutorial)

```
pragma solidity 0.5.4;
contract MyContractEtherEvents {
   mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
   address payable wallet;
   event Purchase(
    address indexed _buyer,
    uint256 _amount
   );

   constructor(address payable _wallet) public {
    wallet = _wallet;
   }

   function() external payable {
     buyToken();
   }

   function buyToken() public payable {
    balances[msg.sender] += 1;
    wallet.transfer(msg.value);
    emit Purchase(msg.sender, 1);
   }
 }
 I got the following Ether log:
```

> transaction hash
>     0xa4484b15bd6e83c5377bbc4e21f69e8c208a02c3ea0187ffa77cb29c9352df6e 
>   from  0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c  to
>     MyContractEtherEvents.balances(address)
>   0x692a70D2e424a56D2C6C27aA97D1a86395877b3A  transaction cost  23832
>   gas (Cost only applies when called by a contract)  execution cost
>     1152 gas (Cost only applies when called by a contract)  hash
>     0xa4484b15bd6e83c5377bbc4e21f69e8c208a02c3ea0187ffa77cb29c9352df6e 
>   input     0x27e...a733c  decoded input    {   "address ":
>   "0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c" }  decoded output    {
>     "0": "uint256: 4

The 'from' address is: 0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c (correct) but 'to' address is: 0x692a70D2e424a56D2C6C27aA97D1a86395877b3A, which is the address at which the contract is deployed. But the remix image does not show the deployed address instead it shows the address : 0x147…C160C which is the address of Wallet. Is the log information correct? I have also added the image, the image does not show the 'to' address

Some body please guide me.
Zulfi.

[image: Problem with understanding the transaction log]

Answer (score 1):

Expand the transaction receipt to see the log.

[image]

Hope it helps.